# How can I grant owning group permissions when POSIX ACLs are applied?

Tags: chmod, posix, acl

I am trying to understand how I can grant permissions to the owning group once POSIX ACLs have been applied to a file.
Normally, I would use `chmod g+rwx`. However, that does not work when a POSIX ACL was applied via setfacl before. I am not able to access the file with a member of the owning group afterwards.
The output of getfacl shows that the owning group entry has not changed but the mask has.

```
[vagrant@ice01 tmp]$ umask 077
[vagrant@ice01 tmp]$ touch test
[vagrant@ice01 tmp]$ ls -lisa test
1585067 0 -rw------- 1 vagrant vagrant 0 Sep 23 17:43 test
[vagrant@ice01 tmp]$ setfacl -m u:icer01:rwx test
[vagrant@ice01 tmp]$ chmod g+rwx test
[vagrant@ice01 tmp]$ ls -lisa test
1585067 0 -rw-rwx---+ 1 vagrant vagrant 0 Sep 23 17:43 test
[vagrant@ice01 tmp]$ getfacl test
# file: test
# owner: vagrant
# group: vagrant
user::rw-
user:icer01:rwx
group::---
mask::rwx
other::---
```

I read this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/352915) and it claims:

> If you use the chmod(1) command to change the file group owner permissions on a file with ACL entries, *either* the file group owner permissions *or* the ACL mask are changed to the new permissions.

I read parts of the referenced IEEE 1003.1e working draft and it backs their claim.
But more importantly: I could confirm this behavior on a CentOS 6 box with an ext4 filesystem (see above).

Am I correct in assuming, that `setfacl` is the only option to grant access to the owning group once an ACL has been applied?

If so, that behavior shifts reponsibility to the end-user. In the end you have to check whether ACLs are already set, before you decide whether to use `chmod` or `setfacl`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question in the title is: `setfacl -m group::rwX test` The capital X means "only grant execute permission if someone else already has execute permission." (It means the same thing to `chmod(1)`.) Using capital X is how you can do a recursive `setfacl` or `chmod` to grant permission without ending up with executable source files.

The ACL entry `group::` corresponds to the current group of the file. If you were to change the group of `test` to something other than vanguard the `group::` entry would control access for whatever the current group is.

`chmod g+rwx` didn't do what you expected because when there is an ACL the Unix group permission bits on a file or directory are aliased with the `mask::` entry of the ACL. As long as there is an ACL `chmod g+FOO` will be equivalent to `setfacl -m mask::FOO` and vice versa.

Comment: For more on the mask, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475698/ .